# free dragging shapes on android

Tags: android

I tried implementing dragging on android in 2 ways:

1. Canvas with on draw.
2. Relative layout with margins changes on touch.

It's not smooth enough, even on strong devices.

How can I make dragging faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way (and most responsive) is to handle touches in your view, and when you handle a `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE`, simply set your `View`'s x and y points from the event's raw coordinates and call `view.invalidate()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a higher performance alternative to simply calling `invalidate()` and redrawing your view contents, use a `SurfaceView` which provides you a drawing surface that you can draw on from any thread.  You are still given a `Canvas` to draw on, you just obtain access and draw on it whenever you like with code like:

```
SurfaceView mSurface; //In your view hierarchy
SurfaceHolder = mSurface.getHolder();
Canvas c = mHolder.lockCanvas();

c.drawBitmap(...);
c.drawColor(...);
//...etc...etc...

mHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
```

Rather than waiting for `draw()` calls to be made to your view.  As I mentioned, since you obtain a lock on the `Canvas`, this drawing can be done on a background thread.

HTH